# Static Constructor behaviour (C#)

Tags: c#

How the static constructor is behaving here ?

```
class a
{    
    public static int x;
    static a()
    {
        x = b.y + 1;    
    }
}

class b    
{    
    public static int y = a.x + 1;

    static b()
    { 

    }

    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("x={0} , y={1} ", a.x, b.y);
        Console.ReadLine();    
    }
}
```

Output ::

x=1 , y=2

How ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is, except for case, the exact example given [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645612%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), which gives the following explanation:

> To execute the Main method, the system first runs the initializer for B.Y, prior to class B's static constructor. Y's initializer causes A's static constructor to be run because the value of A.X is referenced. The static constructor of A in turn proceeds to compute the value of X, and in doing so fetches the default value of Y, which is zero. A.X is thus initialized to 1. The process of running A's static field initializers and static constructor then completes, returning to the calculation of the initial value of Y, the result of which becomes 2.

Answer (score 4):

Everything starts from this line

`public static int y = a.x + 1`;

- it goes to `a.x`
- after  to `a` type, so `public static int x;` initialized, and static

  ```
  static a()
  {
      x = b.y + 1;    
  }
  ```

ctor invoked.

- In this ctor `b.y` is already *staticaly* initilized so we get `b.y` **current** value, which is `0`,

so `x = 0 + 1`.

- After we come back to `public static int y = a.x + 1;`

where `a.x` is `1`, so it becomes `int y = 1 + 1;`

Answer (score 0):

1. `b.y` is initialized, causing `a` to get initialized, so
2. `a()` is called, setting `a.x` to `b.y + 1` (`b.y` is still initialized to its default, 0)
3. `b.y` is then set to `a.x + 1` (`a.x` has been initialized to 1)

I would avoid this in real world code though...

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `b.y` starts out with the default value, 0. So while setting the value of `y`, `a.x` will become 1.

Answer (score 0):

From the C# specifications

> To execute the Main method, the system first runs the initializer for B.Y, prior to class B's static constructor. Y's initializer causes A's static constructor to be run because the value of A.X is referenced. The static constructor of A in turn proceeds to compute the value of X, and in doing so fetches the default value of Y, which is zero. A.X is thus initialized to 1. The process of running A's static field initializers and static constructor then completes, returning to the calculation of the initial value of Y, the result of which becomes 2.

the line

```
x = b.y + 1;
```

is executed as

```
x = 0 +1;
```

because at this time it has not yet been possible to eveluate the value of b.y and the value of b.y is therefor it's default value (0)

the programs then continues to evaluate the statement

```
y = a.x + 1;
```

and since a.x was assign the value of 1 in the above statement the above is

```
y = 1 + 1;
```

the result in the end is that `x == 1` and `y == 2`